# Analise multivariada com apenas uma tabela

Tags: classificação, r

1 Estou tentando relacionar quantidades de poliquetas em amostras de ostras de locais diferentes, os locais e quantidades estão na mesma tabela, comecei pelo boxplot para ter medias e variaveis no R, consegui visualizar nomeando qual local gostaria de analisar e excluindo colunas quais nao sao necessarias

```
 pinheiros <-pinheiros[,-c(2:4)]
 boxplot(pinheiros, "Vila Fatima")
 boxplot(pinheiros, "Vila Fatima")
 boxplot(pinheiros, "Vila Fatima") -> VF        
 boxplot(pinheiros, "Poruquara") -> PU
 boxplot(pinheiros, "Mangue Pinheiros")-> MG
```

2 gostaria de juntar os 3 em um só, tentei plot mas segue este erro

```
plot("VF" , "PU", "MP")
```

> Error in plot.window(...) : valores finitos são necessários para 'xlim'
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
>   2: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
>   3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
>   5: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   6: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: Opa, seria mais fácil ajudar com uma amostra dos dados. Tente `dput(head(dados))`. Mas já falando que sua função `plot` não é válida. Você cria um gráfico com um x e um y e depois pode adicionar mais dados com `lines` ou `points`. Mas se  o resultado for os 3 boxplots juntos você pode usar `boxplot(VF , PU, MP)`.

Comment: Instruções como `boxplot(pinheiros, "Vila Fatima")` não fazem sentido, a string `"Vila Fatima"` não está lá a fazer nada. Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(pinheiros)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(pinheiros, 20))`? A base `pinheiros` já depois de filtrada com a primeira intrução da pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir vários plots você pode utilizar.
`
par(mfrow=c(2,1))

plot(VF)
plot(PU)
....
` 
Mas o ideal é o dput, para corrigir este erro louco ae.